# Laravel controller session store/retrieve troubles

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm having troubles storing/retrieving data from session. My session variable from_date is not set. At beginning, I'm checking if session has no value.

```
    if (!($request->session()->has('from_date')))
    {
        $from= date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, "01", date("Y")));
        session(['from_date' => $from]);            
    }
    else
    {
       $from=$request->session()->get('from_date');              
    }
```

Comment: By "not changing" you mean it's not being set at all?

Comment: Yes. I changed in description.

Comment: how do u set the session?

Comment: Check the session cookie that's being sent to the sent to the server and the one that's being returned. Make sure they match otherwise the session would not be maintained. Also, make sure your route belongs to a group that runs the `StartSession` middleware

Comment: @Sletheren
Session is "empty" or has been not set before.

Comment: then try to `$request->session()->put('from_date', 'value'); `